# In Azure Stream Analytics query how do you concatenate strings together?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I'm attempting to modify one of my data values by concatenating a string to a date.

Below is what I've tried for my query but there seems to be some problem with my syntax.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: sorry the query in in the image "enter image description here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting to a string first:

```
CONCAT(
 CAST(created as nvarchar(max)),
 ' something else to concatenate' 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the query it will tell you what's wrong with the syntax.

Anyway, the problem it is likely to be that the `created` column is not a text format so it needs to be converted to a `VARCHAR` before being used by the `CONCAT` function. Try changing it to:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(created AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ', XXX-YOUR-TEXT-XXX') AS NewName
[...]
```

Plenty of query examples here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns/